# SQL Server 2016 Express edition and developer edition on same machine

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server 2016 Express edition and Developer edition on the same machine, but when I use SSMS to login, and type

```
select @@version
```

only express edition is shown, why?

[image]

SSMS login method

[image]

sql server configuration manager as follow:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it'll only show you the one you're connected to. How exactly are you connecting? Are you specifying an instance name?

Comment: I have added the login screen now

Comment: The screenshots show you connected to the Developer edition, not Express. You'd have to enter `192.168.152.15\SQLExpress` to connect to Express

Answer (score 2):

The two instances will have a separate **instance name** -  and you can connect to only one at a time.

By default, the SQL Server Express will use  `SQLEXPRESS` as its instance name, while Developer edition will default to the unnamed instance.

You can connect:

- to SQL Server **Express** by using `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` as your server/instance name
- to SQL Server **Developer** by using `(local)` as your server/instance name

Both should be available - and again, those are the **default** instance names - you may have changed those to something else during installation, and in that case, you have to use those values you used, of course.

**UPDATE:** to find the instance names, go to your SQL Server Configuration Manager (from the start menu), and look at this screen:

[image]

Find the `SQL Server` services that are running - in parenthesis behind the "SQL Server", you see the instance names - in my case `SQL2014` and `SQL2016`. The `MSSQLSERVER` is the **default, unnamed** instance that you can connect to using just `(local)` (or your IP address) without specifying an instance name

**Update #2:** examining your screenshot, it seems like you're using the default instance names - none (unnamed default) instance - which is most likely your developer edition, and `SQLEXPRESS` which is the default for SQL Express.

So if you login to `(local)` and run `SELECT @@VERSION` - do you get the Developer edition? And if you login to `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` and run `SELECT @@VERSION`, do you get the Express edition?? You might replace `(local)` with your IP address ...

Comment: I have added my login method screen dump, how to know my developer instance name?

Comment: very strange, I can only run one instance in sql server configuration Manager, if I run SQL server (MSSQLSERVER), then use (local) to login and type SELECT @@VERSION, it return developer edition, but then SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) cannot be run in sql server configuration manager.

and If I stopped SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER) in sql server configuraiton manger, then I can start SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) in sql server configuration manger, but I can just use (local) in SSMS to login and 
select @@version return express edition.